# Get the first and last names corresponding to their id

Tags: php

**Problem**

So, I have no idea as to how I can can do this but what I want to do is to get the first and last name's of the leader and the students using their id. After I've got the first and last names of the students and leader, I need to output it.

**Teams Table**

```
id | leaderID | studentID
1  | 123      | 123456
2  | 123      | 09
3  | 123      | 7776
4  | 233      | 80
5  | 233      | 997
```

**Student's Table**

```
studentID | firstname | lastname | teacherID
----------|-----------|----------|----------
123       | Dave      | Jackson  | 23
123456    | Jessie    | Roberts  | 23
09        | Rick      | Rustels  | 24
7776      | Blake     | Jackson  | 25
80        | Ashly     | Kenson   | 23
233       | Lilly     | Street   | 25
997       | Billy     | Street   | 24
```

**What I'm Currently Getting (First id is the leader's id)**

```
123
123456
09
7776

233
80
997
```

**What I want**

```
Dave Jackson
Jessie Roberts
Rick Rustels
Blake Jackson

Lilly Street
Ashly Kenson
Billy Street
```

So basically I want to get the first and last names corresponding to their ID.

**PHP Code**

```
<?php 

require '../connect.php';

$team_data = $link->prepare("SELECT leaderID, studentID, CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) as firstlast FROM teams, students Order by leaderID, studentID");
$team_data->execute();
$team_data = $team_data->fetchAll();

if(!$team_data) {
    header("Location: ../../admin.php?msg=Sorry we could not get the data");
}

$data = [];

foreach ($team['firstlast'] as $team) {
    $leader_id = $team['leaderID'];
    $student_id = $team['studentID'];
    $data[$leader_id][] = $student_id;
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Teams</title>
</head>
<body>

    <?php foreach ($data as $leader_id => $students): ?>
        <ul>
            <li><strong><?php echo $leader_id; ?></strong></li>
                <?php foreach ($students as $student_id): ?>
            <li><?php echo $student_id; ?></li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you select IDs, you get IDs... just add `firstname and lastname` in your query, no ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Single Query

```sql
(
  SELECT 1 AS leader, s.studentID AS leaderID, s.studentID,
    s.firstname, s.lastname
  FROM teams AS t
  JOIN students AS s ON s.studentID = t.leaderID
  GROUP BY t.leaderID
) UNION (
  SELECT 0 AS leader, t.leaderID, s.studentID, s.firstname, s.lastname
  FROM teams AS t
  JOIN students AS s ON s.studentID = t.studentID
) ORDER BY 2, 1 DESC;
```

The query consists of two `SELECT`s combined with a `UNION`. The first selects only the leaders removing duplicates with `GROUP BY`. The second sub-query selects the rest of the students. Finally, the result set is sorted by leader ID in ascending order, and by the `leader` flag in descending order.

*Sample Output*

```
leader leaderID studentID firstname lastname
1      123      123       Dave      Jackson
0      123      9         Rick      Rustels
0      123      7776      Blake     Jackson
0      123      123456    Jessie    Roberts
1      233      233       Lilly     Street
0      233      80        Ashly     Kenson
0      233      997       Billy     Street
```

Note, you will likely need to optimize the table structures in order to run this query without performance penalties. For example, you may need to add indexes for `leaderID` and `studentID` columns.

### Two Queries + PHP

Often a few simple queries are faster than a single complex query. Also, in some cases sorting and grouping operations are faster when implemented in PHP rather than in SQL. The following is another approach which will likely run faster than the above-mentioned complex query. Make some benchmarks in order to figure out which is better for your case.

```
<?php
$result = [];

// Collect only leaders
$q = 'SELECT s.studentID, s.firstname, s.lastname
    FROM students AS s, teams AS t
    WHERE t.leaderID = s.studentID
    GROUP BY 1';
$cursor = Db::query($q);
while ($row = Db::fetchNext($cursor)) {
    $result[$row['studentID']][] = $row;
}
$cursor->free();

// Collect the rest
$q = 'SELECT s.studentID, t.leaderID, s.firstname, s.lastname
    FROM students AS s, teams AS t
    WHERE t.studentID = s.studentID';
$cursor = Db::query($q);
while ($row = Db::fetchNext($cursor)) {
    $leader_id = $row['leaderID'];
    if (isset($result[$leader_id])) {
        $result[$leader_id][] = $row;
    }
}
$cursor->free();
```

The first block selects only leaders and stores them into `$result` by `studentID` keys.

The second block collects the rest of the students and stores them in similar way into `$result`, if corresponding `leaderID` exists. (You can skip this check by passing leader IDs to `WHERE` clause via `IN()`.)

Since `$result` is initially filled with leaders, the leaders will be stored at the first positions:

```
Array
(
    [123] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [studentID] => 123
                    [firstname] => Dave
                    [lastname] => Jackson
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [studentID] => 123456
                    [leaderID] => 123
                    [firstname] => Jessie
                    [lastname] => Roberts
                )
                (skipped...)
        )

    [233] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [studentID] => 233
                    [firstname] => Lilly
                    [lastname] => Street
                )
                (skipped...)
        )
)
```

---

<sub>`Db::query()` and `Db::fetchNext()` are imaginary functions. The former performs an SQL query on the database and returns cursor to the result set. The latter fetches the next result using the cursor.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Using sql: `CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname)`:

Change:

```
$team_data = $link->prepare("SELECT leaderID, studentID FROM teams order by leaderID, studentID");
```

To:

```
$team_data = $link->prepare("SELECT leaderID, studentID, CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) as firstlast FROM teams, students Order by leaderID, studentID");
```

Then inside the `foreach`, you can use `$team['firstlast']`

Comment: Its telling me `Unknown column 'firstname' in 'field list'`. There is no `firstname` or `lastname` in the teams table, only in the students table

Comment: Updated the sql statement to select from multiple tables. Check above

Comment: Now its telling me: `Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'studentID' in field list is ambiguous` at line 6 which is: `$team_data->execute();`. I updated my code so you know what I currently have.

Answer (score 0):

Since your first/last names are found in the student table, you need to join that table. So your query should become:

```
$team_data = $link->prepare("SELECT a.leaderID, a.studentID, CONCAT(b.firstname, ' ', b.lastname) AS full_name FROM teams AS a LEFT JOIN stundent_table AS b ON a.studentID = b.studentID ORDER BY a.leaderID, a.studentID");
```

Whatever your student table name is. Change that accordingly.